# if greater than in C#

Tags: c#, if-statement

Edit: Problem solved, the greater than was the wrong ascii character. Even tho I didn't copy paste it from somewhere. I'll have to check my keyboard language.

Edit: Just to make it clear, effect.Parry is an int? not a decimal. See edit below
Edit: I changed the decimalToString. That was an error on my part but I'm still getting the error

I am trying to do a greater than if statement in my code but I am getting an error and I just can't figure what the error is...

Here is the part of the code.

```
 if (effect.Parry != null)
                {
                    txtEffect += " Parry the next " + effect.Parry.ToString() + " attack";
                    if (effect.Parry ­> 1) 
                        txtEffect += "s";
                    if (effect.NumberOfTurn != 0)
                    {
                        txtEffect += " over " + effect.NumberOfTurn.ToString();
                    }
                }
```

And here is the error I get:

```
Erreur  1   Caractère '-­' inattendu
```

In english it would be: Unexpected character '-'

Can someone explain me what I did wrong? I tried ­>= and it gives me the same error. If I try without > I don't get an error.

Edit: txtEffect is a string, effect.Parry is an int? (To allow nulls) I tried parsing it into a normal int and I get the same error as above.

Comment: What's the content of `effect.Parry`?

Comment: What is effect.Parry? We need to see more before we can help you.

Comment: What is the value of `effect.Parry` when you parse it?

Comment: Show us decialToString too

Comment: i'm guessing effect.Parry is a decimal..

Comment: I don't think the error comes from here. Don't you have a line number given with the error ?

Comment: That's a compile-time error, and it isn't coming from this code.

Comment: what line is throwing the exception?

Comment: I edited to answer the comments and the error come directly from the greater than. The line and column are straight on it and I don't get the error if I change it to ==

Comment: Could we see the full code for the class that this is a part of?

Comment: Could `effect.Parry` contain a *negative* number (hence the complaint about `-`) and for some reason be having its type misinterpreted? Is there any logic in the `Parry` property's getter that could be at fault?

Comment: if parry is a decimal try effect.Parry >= 1m

Comment: If effect.Parry is an int?, then why are you passing it into a method taking a decimal? as input?

Comment: @SeanCogan yes now I see. That's my error. thank you Edit: I changed it aand I still get the same error :s

Comment: If changing `==` to `>=` makes the error appear, I think the error comes from `txtEffect += "s";` Are you sure it's a string? What is its contents at the moment of doing this code?

Comment: @snaplemouton I posted that comment as an answer just so others can see it.

Comment: @snaplemouton Are you working in Visual Studio? Please turn on the debugger, and have it break on exceptions. So you at least know the line number causing the error

Comment: @snaplemouton: Can you post your _whole_ code file? I suspect may have bad syntax somewhere that's throwing everything off.

Comment: @nl-x I am and like I said, it's the same line, same column.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair I'd love to do so but my whole code is about a thousand of lines. I'll edit and try to put as much information as I can

Comment: _"my whole code is about a thousand of lines"_ Well there's your problem! :)

Comment: The problem appears to be due to your ">" character not being an actual ASCII 3E.  I'm guessing you pasted it from somewhere.  Try overwriting it with a manually typed ">" character.

Comment: (Darn I was just writing the actual answer when the question was closed!) The character you are using for the minus sign is wrong.
You are using this one: -  (Ascii Code 0xAD) But the one you should be using is this one: - (code 0x2D)

Comment: what minus sign?! I don't see any in his code. Snaplemouton you need to show more code!

Comment: The minus sign is in the actual error message he posted. Try copy-paste it into a program. :)

Comment: Oh wow. copy/paste the `>` character and what do you get? In Visual Studio, it looks like `>`, in Notepad, LINQPad it appears as `->` (really what Matthew Watson posted) EDIT: I kinda want to star/favourite this question for reference in the future of ASCII tomfoolery.

Comment: so both his greather than and minus sign are rigged :) ? sigh

Comment: Never copy directly from webpages!

Comment: @MatthewWatson yes that was exactly the problem. :S I guess I should throw my keyboard throught the window

Comment: Been there... done that.. got the T shirt ;)

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd I didn't...

Comment: Maybe there should be a Stack Overflow badge for throwing the keyboard out the window.

Comment: questions are marked closed TOO early. This question could not have been clearer... `</hindsight>`

Comment: @nl-x, you are saying that a question where the offending code was never shown, it took psychic debugging that assumed a copy-paste with an invalid ASCII character is one that could have never been *clearer*? This is the textbook definition of "not a real question" or "too localized."

Comment: @user414076 the thing is... it wasn't a copy paste... I don't know if it comes from the fact that I use Canadian multingual standard or if it's my keyboard or something... but it wasn't copy paste at all.

Comment: @user414076 the offending code WAS shown. It just took a MatthewWatson and a ChrisSinclair to see it. If the OP was any clearer, then there would have been no more question, would there?

Comment: The 0xAD character in the line `effect.Parry ­> 1` is a soft-hyphen. That (at least sort of) explains why Visual Studio and Stack Overflow don't show it. I'd almost like to open an issue at Microsoft Connect to see what sort of response they'd give.

Comment: So why is this program illegal? `interface Ι{} class C: I {}` ?  :-) Start putting those in your source code next April Fools Day and see how long it takes your coworkers to notice.

Comment: @snaplemouton Yes, it's your keyboard. Or more specifically, the Windows Canadian Multilingual Standard keyboard service. `Right-Ctrl + Shift + /` produces a soft-hyphen. If I had to guess, that key combination is probably similar to one you use semi-regularly.

Comment: @JoelRondeau Thank you for the confirmation. :)

Answer (score -1):

Your problem came from defining effect.Parry as an int? and then passing it into a function requiring a decimal? as a parameter. Change one or the other so they match, and you should take care of your problem.

Comment: `int?` is implicitly convertable to `decimal?`; the code should compile fine for that method call. For example: `public static void Print(decimal? d) {} int? i = 1; Print(i);`

Comment: Ah, I see. I figured since he originally said that was his problem that he meant that my answer fixed it. Sorry about that.